# ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, internet-explorer

While configuring a couple of hosts I'm facing an issues.
If I connect to a certain host using https and internet explorer I get the advice that the  site is not secure but then I can go further on. If I use chrome I'm blocked with a ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE.
I've searched a lot of solution that tells me to import the certificate as trusted CA, but this is not the case (or at least I think) since the certificate is valid as long as his ca and the error difference between the two browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was tuck with same issue created a new self signed certificate and that solved my issue